# Machine won't boot unless it has been plugged in for a day or so

Tags: boot

When I go on vacation, I unplug my computers.

The time before last when I got back, one machine wouldn't boot.  After a couple of days I got around to trying to fix it, but it was fine.

I just got back from vacation again, and again it wouldn't boot.  Based on what happened the first time, I just left it plugged in and kept trying it.  After 1 1/2 days it started up normally.

FWIW it's an old Elonex Exentia: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2003/11/26/elonex_exentia_media_center_pc/

Any obvious causes and remedies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of things like this is a bad/faulty power supply unit, however, as your machine uses non standard parts, you may have problems trying to find a replacement.

Comment: Capacitors going, perhaps? Definitely sounds like a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cant's say this is a solution, but I have had weird experience with my old computer. After I replace the little battery everything is back to normal

Comment: You mean the CMOS battery.

Comment: yup I think so (well I don't know what it's called)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer , but I did have a monitor which had bad capacitors .This particular monitor took maybe 1 day to start .  Maybe your PSU's caps don't hold (enough)power and need a long time to get enough power to start ?